# Run Hello World on ARM emulator

Tags: c, assembly, arm, emulation, cpu

I'm trying to emulate a ARM-cpu at the moment. I read a lot about how to emulate a cpu. Right now I managed to write down all OpCodes, Registers etc and compiled a Hello World on a ARM-Maschine written in C, to get the assembler code (to test my emulator).

**Assembler**

```
    .arch armv8-a
    .file "hello.c"
    .section .text.startup, "ax", @progbits
    .align 2
    .p2align 3,,7
    .global main
    .type main, %function
main:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
    adrp x1, .LC0
    add x1, x1, :lo12:.LC0
    mov w0, 1
    add x29, sp, 0
    bl __printf_chk
    mov w0, 0
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16
    ret
    .size main, .-main
    .section .rodata.str1.8, "aMS", @progbits, 1
    .align 3
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World"
    .ident "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)"
    .section .note.GNU-stack, "", @progbits
```

I have to load the code from the ROM to my emulated RAM from which the code will be executed. But how do I load it to the RAM? I dont understand how to split the OpCodes and the Registers.

**Summary**

I want to emulate a ARM-CPU on a Intel CPU with Windows. To test my emulator I wrote a Hello World in C and compiled it to get the assembler code. The assembler code is written on a ARM-Maschine with Ubuntu 16.04. My question is how to fetch the assembler code with my emulator.

Comment: I can't help but feel that if you are able to write your ***own*** emulator, you should be able to figure out how to (basically) copy data from one memory region to another. Or is that not the problem? Can you please elaborate and add more details? What *exactly* do you have? What *exactly* are you trying to do? What *exactly* have you done?

Comment: You talk about copying, and about "splitting opcodes and registers".  Do you mean operands in general, including immediates?  So are you having problems with relocating position-dependent code to a different guest address?  This is why object file formats have relocations.  A relocation entry describes which bytes need to be modified, so you don't need to decode the machine code.

Comment: As far as I know, the emulator has to copy data from ROM to the RAM. But what happens after that? The emulator has to go through the RAM, read the OpCodes, variables, etc.. and execute them. But for example, how does the emulator know if the number (?) is a OpCode or a variable? Sry its kind of hard to explain it.. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: So you haven't even gotten to the stage where the emulator decodes instructions yet? Then you should take a few steps back, and start over (I think) with analysis, requirements and design. And most importantly learn about the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files, how to load them properly, and of course the binary format of the ARM instructions and what *each single bit* in them mean. In short, you're going way to fast and need to slow down.

Comment: _"As far as I know, the emulator has to copy data from ROM to the RAM."_ Why? Was the code compiled to be run from RAM? There are plenty of examples where most code would run from ROM (e.g. pretty much every cartridge-based video game console).